# Getting information from database dynamically

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, dynamic

I have a datalist on my page which displays a number of rows from my database as options. I would like the user to be able to choose one of the options in the datalist, and the page to get the rest of the information of that particular thing from the database and change the HTML on the page to output that information. I understand there is a way of doing this without the need to reload the page, like you would have to using PHP, if you use AJAX. I just have no clue how. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on this reference http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
With jQuery it is very easy (jQuery is a JavaScript framework)

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'test.php',
     data: {"type":"check"},
     success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
         //This is your content you get from your php file, now you can assign it to html using jQuery
         $('p.print').html(response);
     }
});
```

Datalist means you have a selectbox? So call the ajax request inside something like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   $(this).val(); //Get the option which was selected
   //Ajax request here regarding to the selected option
});
```

Comment: Just an addition and a note for the OP: jQuery .html() and .text() methods may be also useful for refreshing page components, after the AJAX request.

Comment: I know I am pushing it, but could you elaborate on how to implement this to a PHP file? I am not familiar with neither jQuery nor AJAX Im afraid...

Comment: PHP is server site, if you want to do something dynamically you need a browser site language like JavaScript/jQuery. With only PHP that is not possible. You need both in order to do that. If you refresh your whole page you can do something with PHP, but you can't react on events or something dynamically without a page reload. For this things you need JavaScript

Comment: Yes, that I am aware of. I just meant how you combine the two. As I understand, the url: "test.php" is supposed to link to a php file that handles getting the information from the database, yes? And what does the data: {"type":"check"} do? I am sorry for being annoying here...

Comment: {"type":"check"} is just an example. You can send data during the request to your PHP file. The data format that you use to send this is JSON, look in Google what JSON is. In your case you want to send the option that was selected on the frontend to your PHP file. You can do this with this using the "data" attribute. Afterwards you can read those "parameters" in your PHP file and react to that. For example read the regarding values from the database that you have passed to the PHP file

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to send an ajax request to the server to get data when a javascript change event is triggered on your datalist. Assuming you're using jQuery:

```
$('SELECTOR_FOR_DATALIST').on('change', function() {
    var record_id = $(this).val(); // this gets the value of your selected data
    var data = {
        'id': record_id
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'endpoint.php', // this is your endpoint for server side processing
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            // here's where you'll handle a successful response from the server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle error response here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I know Im asking for much, Im sorry, but how would I go about making the endpoint php file? I mean, I do know how to get information from a database, I just dont know jQuery enough to know what is what here. To be able to select the proper information from the database, I need a variable to compare the information in the database with, in this case, what the user chose. What will that variable be in the endpoint php file after it has been passed through jQuery?

Comment: like you said, you need to pass a variable (an ID) in order to find what you need from the database. In this case, you'll need the user's choice. $(this).val() will give you that value. $(this) refers to the jquery object that triggered the 'change' event, aka the user's choice. and you're sending that information as 'id' to the endpoint. in your php script, you'll get the 'id' variable from the request and that's the user's choice

Comment: Ah, I see, so in the end I will have a PHP variable in the endpoint script called $id that I will be able to use in the script. How does jQuery then retrieve what the PHP script has gotten?

Comment: your php script should return a json object with all the information you need. and that response is the 'response' in the 'success' callback. refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ to the success callback option

Comment: I shall try this tomorrow, as it is 2 AM where I am, and notify you about how it went :P